# Extract first column and last column of a Numpy array and populate on one dimension array

Tags: numpy

I am a novice on Numpy.

I have extracted a CSV file and with the condition to populate the array below

```py
data = [(2006, 'Total Live-Births', 38317) (2007, 'Total Live-Births', 39490)
 (2008, 'Total Live-Births', 39826) (2009, 'Total Live-Births', 39570)
 (2010, 'Total Live-Births', 37967) (2011, 'Total Live-Births', 39654)
 (2012, 'Total Live-Births', 42663) (2013, 'Total Live-Births', 39720)
 (2014, 'Total Live-Births', 42232) (2015, 'Total Live-Births', 42185)
 (2016, 'Total Live-Births', 41251)]
```

I wanted to plot a bar chart using  years and the counts and I probably need to store an `x` array and a `y` array
how do I get the following?

```py
x=[2006, 2007, 2008,....]
y=[39826, 39490, 39826, ...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your data as follows:
Just sticking to `numpy` you could do something like:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('live-births.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1, dtype=str)
# keep only the 'Total Live-Births' values
live_births = data[data[:, 1] == 'Total Live-Births']

x = live_births[:, 0].astype(int)
y = live_births[:, 2].astype(int)
```

Using `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('live-births.csv')

# keep only the 'Total Live-Births' values
df = df[df['level_1'] == 'Total Live-Births']

# get as numpy arrays
x = df['year'].values.astype(int)
y = df['value'].values.astype(int)
```

Comment: Hi stefan, thank you very much. I tried the numpy code it shows me some errors " too many indices for array. Array is one dimensional but two were indexed. The error point to x = data[:, 0].astype(int)

Comment: import numpy as np
#import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#5. Bar charts Task 1 – Analyse live births  
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fname = "Data\live-births.csv"
data = np.genfromtxt(fname, delimiter=',',skip_header=1, 
            dtype=[('year','i8'),('level_1','U50'),('value','i8')],
            missing_values=['na'],filling_values=0)

Comment: year=[2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]
data_1960=data[data['year']==1960]
keyword = 'Total Live-Births'

column_to_search = data['level_1']
column_to_search1 = data['year']
out = [i for i, v in enumerate(column_to_search) if keyword in v]
out = [i for i, v in enumerate(column_to_search1) if v in year ]
data= (data[out])

Comment: As long as the data actually looks like what you've provided it'll create an array of shape `(11, 3)` in this case. If you could share a sample of the csv I'd be able to adapt where necessary.

Comment: Hi stefan please find the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/17owIRzGcAlDVwnnNAs7pCxHxxhx-Z_SJ/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: hi Stefan , Got it. Thank you for your great help